# Bluez sending ext scan rsp data command even when the Legacy PDU is set in Ext Adv Params

Tags: bluez

Linux kernel : 5.4.24
We are using bluez with a 5.0 feature enabled controller. When doing `hciconfig hci0 reset` we can see that in `LE Set Extended Advertising Parameters` even when properties is set as ADV_NONCONN_IND legacy as below:

```
< HCI Command: LE Set Extended Advertising Parameters (0x08|0x0036) plen 25                           #83 [hci0] 9.977909
        Handle: 0x00
    Properties: 0x0010
              Use legacy advertising PDUs: ADV_NONCONN_IND
```

We can still see bluez sending `Ext Scan Rsp Data` as below:

```
< HCI Command: LE Set Extended Scan Response Data (0x08|0x0038) plen 35                               #87 [hci0] 9.984415
        Handle: 0x00
        Operation: Complete scan response data (0x03)
        Fragment preference: Minimize fragmentation (0x01)
        Data length: 0x0c
        Name (complete): pvqseqevk
```

And since spec says :

> If the advertising set is non-scannable and the Host uses this command other
> than to discard existing data, the Controller shall return the error code Invalid
> HCI Command Parameters (0x12).

The controller is returning this error:

```
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                                           #88 [hci0] 9.989066
      LE Set Extended Scan Response Data (0x08|0x0038) ncmd 1
        Status: Invalid HCI Command Parameters (0x12)
```

Also, after this command the next commands are passing as seen in hcidump/btmon, but the kernel throws error because this command fails.
My question is , what is the expected behavior?
If this behavior is correct, should we just ignore the error?
If the behavior is wrong, is there any fix already for this?

Comment: Basically, the question and answer is same as:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61935284/invalid-params-issue-when-doing-hciconfig-hci0-reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61935284/invalid-params-issue-when-doing-hciconfig-hci0-reset)